# Returning Some Variable from a "proc" in Tcl

Tags: tcl

Suppose that a procedure in Tcl is as follows:

```
proc Section {ID x y} {
.
.
"Some calculations do here"
.
.
}

Section 1 20 30
Section 2 25 35
Section 3 30 40
Section 4 35 45
```

Now, I define this:

```
set IDsection {1 3}
```

Then, I would like to read **all** values (arbitrary number, 2 or more) into a set (`IDsection`) which would show the ID in above procedure and generate the corresponding `y`:

```
set Load {30 40}
```

How I do produce the values in {} in front of "Load"?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Can you show an attempt you made and what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
proc Section {ID x y} { 
    set ::section_data($ID) [list $x $y] 
}

proc getLoads {ids} {
    global section_data
    foreach id $ids {
        lappend loads [lindex $section_data($id) end]
    }
    return $loads
}

Section 1 20 30
Section 2 25 35
Section 3 30 40
Section 4 35 45

set IDsection {1 4 1 3}

set Load [getLoads $IDsection]   ;# => 30 45 30 40
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! In your code, if I substitute 'set IDsection {1 1 3}', I expect the output to be '30 30 40' while it puts: '30 40' (combining the same data)! Another problem is that your code sorts the results! For example, if you substitute 'set IDsection {1 4 3}', the result will be '30 40 45' while appropriate answer should be '30 45 40'!